# Is this house wired with copper and at least a 100A service?

Tags: wiring, copper, aluminum

Is this house copper wired and 100 amp?

I opened up the breaker box and see mostly copper colored wiring. And the largest breakers at the top of the breaker box are stamped with 100.

My mom has owned this since it was built in the 1960s. We are trying to switch insurance companies but they are asking these things:

Does the home's electrical system have both circuit breakers and at least 100 AMP service? (We have a circuit breaker and it's stamped with 100. So would I answer yes to this?)

Does the home have any aluminum wiring? (No. From what I can see, should I say no?)

Are all outlets and switches aluminum-rated? (Would I answer yes or no to this if the wiring is copper?)

Anyone know if my answers would be correct or what I should answer? I have attached pics and can take more if helpful. Some wires I can see the color of wiring clearly). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't give answers without pictures. If you can't upload here due to image size limits then unload to imgur or another service and add links.

Comment: If everything is copper, leave the aluminum rating question blank.

Answer (score 5):

If all the wires coming into the breakers are copper, you *probably* have copper wiring. There is some chance that there's aluminum wire elsewhere in the house. You'd have to inspect some switch and outlet boxes to be closer to sure. It could be that aluminum connects to copper at a junction box elsewhere, though this is highly unlikely.

Whether your devices are rated for aluminum is irrelevant if you have none. It's also not relevant that the large service cables may be aluminum. That's not what the question is concerned with.

If there are no *fuses* (screw-in or tubular cartridge type), you have breakers. Even if you have *some* fuses, for purposes of insurance or whatever, you have fuses. Period.

You have at least a 100A service if the large, separate main breaker is stamped with 100 or higher. From your description it's not clear if that's true.

Comment: I had a house built in 1990 that was copper except for the A/C, which was Aluminum, so you need to actually inspect each wire in the box.